# Binding Textblock with datacontext code behing

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, code-behind

I want to bind a border generated dynamically from code behind.

below is my model that I bind with the border.

```
public class MapTextboxGridModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MaptextBoxGridStylePropertiesModel _GridStyleProperties = new MaptextBoxGridStylePropertiesModel();
    public MaptextBoxGridStylePropertiesModel GridStyleProperties
    {
        get { return _GridStyleProperties; }
        set
        {
            _GridStyleProperties = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GridStyleProperties");
        }
    }
}
```

My style for each cells is in the _GridStyleProperties. And in _GridStyleProperties model I have one property "_Name" as below.

```
public class MaptextBoxGridStylePropertiesModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string _Name = "Enter your text";
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set
    {
        _Name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}}


// following border(multiple, so I will have border in each cell of the grid) is created inside a grid


MapTextboxGridModel cellcontext = new MapTextboxGridModel();
Border db = new Border();
db.MouseLeftButtonDown += db_MouseLeftButtonDown;
db.DataContext = cellcontext;
TextBlock block = new TextBlock() { Text = cellcontext.GridStyleProperties.Name };
```

and then when I click on any of the cell in the grid.

```
void db_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (columnpossition == -1 && rowpossition == -1)
        {
            columnpossition = Grid.GetColumn(sender as Border);
            rowpossition = Grid.GetRow(sender as Border);
        }
        else
        {
            Border bod = sender as Border;
            Grid grd = bod.Parent as Grid;
            int col = Grid.GetColumn(bod);
            int row = Grid.GetRow(bod);
            if (col == columnpossition && row == rowpossition)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                TextBlock dbtxt = bod.Child as TextBlock;
                imodel.GridStyleProperties.needtoshow = true;
                Binding textbnd = new Binding();
                textbnd.Source = bod.DataContext as MapTextboxGridModel;
                textbnd.Path = new PropertyPath("StyleProperties.Name"); // Is this possible
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(dbtxt, TextBlock.TextProperty, textbnd);
                columnpossition = col;
                rowpossition = row;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't understand where am I making mistake. Please suggest me what change should be done in above code.

Comment: So what is the problem? What is not working? What are the results? Error messages? --> Please help us to identify the actual problem...

Comment: Actually there are no errors. Its not binding with "StyleProperties.Name" when I click on any cell of the grid. It just remains as it is. and when I make change to the "Name" property, the selected cell does not accept the change. So I think the binding is not done in a properer way but  don't understand why.

Comment: Then please integrate this information into the question itself... (That way we don't have to reproduce the whole exercise just to find out WHAT is actually wrong)

Comment: Ok I will just edit my question. thank you